# C++ std::shared_ptr assigning via operator=

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, stl, shared-ptr

I have some parametrized class with pointer private member implemented as `std::shared_ptr`. In fact this pointer is a pointer to a parametrized(template) struct. Also there is a method returning same pointer. But not wrapped in `std::shared_ptr`. It looks like this:

```
template<typename SomeType> class SomeClass{
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<SomeStruct<SomeType>> ptr;         // pointer
        SomeStruct<SomeType>* someMethod(...);             // method
};
```

In my some place within a class's methods I would like to have following assignment:

```
ptr = someMethod(..);
```

Is it correct? In fact I would like this method to allocate memory iff need and then this pointer to be managed by `shared_ptr`. I receive an error that proper `operator=` was not found. Should I first wrap pointers for recenlty allocated objects within my method?

Comment: you can wrap it with a constructor, or easier yet, do your allocation with "make_shared"

Comment: Please **NEVER** return raw-pointers, return smart-pointers. What happens if the user of the function does `delete call_to_function_which_returns_pointer()` and that function is a factory?

Comment: Also note that return-raw-pointer functions interfaces don't show clearly the ownership of the returned object (Pointed by). Herb Sutter writted a GoTW about that, but I didn't found it.

Comment: @Manu343726 Is it a rule also for private methods? (this method is private in fact).

Comment: Probably no, because you are managing the data internally. **BUT its much easier to use smart pointers to not worry about the lifetime/ownership of the pointer**. So use smart pointers always, they make your life easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the very true comment to NEVER return the raw pointer, you have (at least) three options:

- Return the `std::shared_ptr` (every call will update the reference count)
- Return a (const) reference to the `std::shared_ptr` (to avoid the overhead of the reference count in some cases)
- Derive the class from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). Use this as a last resort if you really need to return a plain pointer (or a reference) to the object. Then use `ptr = someMethod(...)->shared_from_this();`

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct and can lead to two independent `shared_ptr` pointing to the same object, which will cause a double deletion:

```
SomeStruct<SomeType>* raw_ptr = someMethod(..);
ptr p1(raw_ptr);
ptr p2(raw_ptr);
```

What you want is [enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). This will allocate the external reference count along with the object so that all constructed shared pointers use the same ref count.

Comment: In fact this method is private, and new object is allocated if current pointer refers to NULL only. It looks like:
`ptr = someMethod(ptr, .. )`

Comment: @vard: So .. `SomeClass` is a singleton?

Comment: @ Lightness No, I've listed in example not all the methods and members. `someMethod` is called within one of public methods.